# Query using LINQ to SharePoint with lambda expression against PeoplePicker - client object model

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lambda

I have a sharepoint 2010 list. I'm writing code against the client object model.

I use CAML to retrieve a set of sharepoint list items.

After that, I need to filter for a subset of these records, based on info that is stored in a People Picker column. (So I only wanna get results, where e.g. the PeoplePicker is set to John Smith.)

I know that in order to access the peoplepicker, it has to be declared as a FieldUserValue. However, I can't seem to do that within a lambda expression.

The below is how things should work ideally. But of course this doesnt compile as I cant declare the "EngineerAccount" as a FieldUserValue within the lambda expression.

```
FieldUserValue usvAss = i["EngineerAccount"] as FieldUserValue;

double totalTT = collListItemAss.Where(item => item["EngineerAccount"] as FieldUserValue == usvAss.LookupValue).Sum(sItem => Convert.ToDouble(sItem["field3"]));
```

Any ideas?

---

I'm sorry this is not solved.

I have 3 points.

**1: This part seems to be unneccessary**

```
`item["EngineerAccount"].GetType() == typeof(FieldUserValue)
```

**2: This code doesnt comply. Also, it is logically incorrect. The "FieldUserValue" is a complex field containing multiple information.** The problem is that I'm trying to 'equate" a FieldUserValue with a string, two different types.

```
(FieldUserValue)item["EngineerAccount"] == usvAss.LookupValue
```

**3: Logically, it should be like this, but this doesnt work:**

```
(FieldUserValue)item["EngineerAccount"].LookupValue == usvAss.LookupValue
```

Please help, I'm out of ideas right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double totalTT = collListItemAss
    .Where(item => ( (item["EngineerAccount"].GetType == typeof(FieldUserValue)) && (((FieldUserValue)(item ["EngineerAccount"])) == usvAss.LookupValue)))
    .Sum(sItem => Convert.ToDouble(sItem["field3"]));
```

Comment: Some1Pr0, thanks a million for the quick answer. This doesnt compile to me. Apparently as I type the "." after "oftype", there is no option to choose "where". If I copy it to VS, oftype is underlined red.

Comment: No probs. Edited please retry

Comment: Almost correct, there were 2 parenthesis missing. However, even with my mod, there is a problem. The ".Sum(sItem)" part is now also declared as a FieldLookupValue, which is incorrect, and hence, I cannot reference the ["field3"].

collListItemAss.Select(item => item["EngineerAccount"]).OfType<FieldUserValue>().Where(x => x == usvAss).Sum(sItem => Convert.ToDouble(sItem["field3"]));

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesnt work either. I'm not sure what the logic is, but why would the "type" of the ListItem be equal to any FieldUserValue? I tried something like this, and it compiles, but gives no results.
 
                double test2 = collListItemAss
                    .Select(item => item["EngineerAccount"])
                    .OfType<FieldUserValue>()
                    .Where(x => x == usvAss)
                    .OfType<ListItem>()
                    .Sum(sItem => Convert.ToDouble(sItem["field3"]));

Comment: Made a mistake try latest edit. Sorry for the last one

Comment: Still no luck. It complains about the double equation signs (==) if I replace those to single (=) it's OK, but the && still isnt. I can't replace those with '&'.

Comment: It complains about the && because you changed the == to = so its not boolean. Which == did yoi change the first or second?

Comment: Both.. I changed it because if I paste it as you wrote, I get the error of: "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'"

Comment: Háhá, I think I got it. This is fine:
                double totalTT = collListItemAss
                    .Where(item => item["EngineerAccount"].GetType() == typeof(FieldUserValue) && (FieldUserValue)item["EngineerAccount"] == usvAss)
                    .Sum(sItem => Convert.ToDouble(sItem["field3"]));
 
A parenthesis was missing after GetType

Comment: Added some ()'s maybe you use a different compiler version so it parsed it differently retry

Comment: Just one more thing.. It seems that FieldUserValue usvAss = i["EngineerAccount"] as FieldUserValue; is actually unique. I thought that FieldUserValue consist only of the LookupID and ~Value

Comment: But this Query you've put together... It only returns 1 value of the "field3". Not the SUM of all field3s

Comment: I dont really know sharepoint i just understood the linq query you were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you mr SomeonePro :) I appreciate your help. I'll take it from here.

Comment: Sorry SomeonePro, this isn't the answer, please see my comments, if you still have the time.

Comment: The first part is neccesary for the application not to crash for type mismatch. What happens when you try number 3?

Comment: You are right, sorry. If I put in option 3 manually, I get "object doesnt contain definition for lookupvalue". Which is due to the fact (I guess) that item["EngineerAccount"] is not treated as FieldLookupValue but as a ListItem.

Comment: Thats because you should write it like that:     ((FieldUserValue)(item["EngineerAccount"])).LookupValue == usvAss.LookupValue

Comment: This seems to be it. I'm sorry for not spotting this... I've only started C# 2 months ago. The script still runs into some problems (code compiling is fine), but that only happens in some of the cases, so the problem lies somewhere else. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :)

Comment: No probs glad i could help